# Memory management in local variable objective-c

Tags: objective-c, memory, memory-management

In one interview i was asked to implement NSArray's exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex: method.
I wrote the following code:

```
- (void)exchangeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index1 withObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index2 {
  id tmp = [self objectAtIndex:index1];
  [self replaceObjectAtIndex:index1 withObject:[self objectAtIndex:index2]];
  [self replaceObjectAtIndex:index2 withObject:tmp];
}
```

Interviewer said here's a memory management problem in first line and I'm going to catch bad_access_exc.
He recommended to write as this:

```
- (void)exchangeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index1 withObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index2 {
    id tmp = [[[self objectAtIndex:index1] retain] autorelease];
    [self replaceObjectAtIndex:index1  withObject:[self objectAtIndex:index2]];
    [self replaceObjectAtIndex:index2 withObject:tmp];
}
```

I understand that his code is right, but since tmp is local variable and it's going to be assigned, so there's no releasing and everything is gonna be ok. Is there any error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you are using manual memory management**, there is an error.  Apple has documented the problem under [“Avoid Causing Deallocation of Objects You’re Using” in the *Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-1000922-BABBFBGJ).

Specifically, `objectAtIndex:` doesn't `retain` and `autorelease` the object that it returns to you.  So the `NSArray` might have the only “owning” reference to the object.  Assigning to `tmp` under manual retain counting (MRC) doesn't retain the object so `tmp` doesn't own it and the autorelease pool doesn't own it.

This means that when line 2 of your method sends `[self replaceObjectAtIndex:index1 withObject:[self objectAtIndex:index2]]`, the array might release the last reference to the object, deallocating it.  At that point, `tmp` refers to a deallocated object; this is called a “dangling reference”.

Then in line 3, you try to put the dangling reference in the array.  The array will send `retain` to the reference, which is invalid, and you will crash or experience heap corruption.

**Under ARC**, assigning to `tmp` **does** retain the object, so there is no error in that case.

Comment: Thanks you, it's really clear explanation. But now I have another misunderstanding: i created empty project and wrote code [posted in pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ykdsk8UW), it should fail but it works well. Why?

I have arc disabled and there seems no any other links to that array.

Comment: The Core Foundation framework caches `NSNumber` instances for the integers from `-1` to `12` inclusive.  Once allocated, these instances are never deallocated.  Search for `MinCachedInt` in [`CFNumber.c`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.18/CFNumber.c) for details.

Comment: It's possible that the static analyzer, or zombies, will detect your bug anyway.  I haven't tried it.

Comment: @RustamGaneyev - It's not *guaranteed* to fail.  It depends whether the released storage is reused for something, and whether the objects in question are retained elsewhere.  If, for example, you made a testcase filling the array with literal strings or literal NSNumbers then odds are they're "interned" (to use the Java term) so they will never be deleted.  But real life can bite you.  (I got bit by this same basic problem once, only in some async code, and it was a bear to trace down.)

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `id tmp` is nothing more than a pointer to the object in your array. It doesn't say anything about the memory management of the object it's pointing to.

> ...it's going to be assigned, so there's no releasing...

This is the sticking point here. You can't guarantee that the object at `index1` won't be deallocated when you replace it with the object at `index2`. In fact, the array will call `release` on it at this point to balance out the `retain` it called on the object when it was originally added to the array. Thus, it's possible that when the object at `index1` is replaced will the object at `index2`, the reference count of the object at `index1` will go to zero, the object will be deallocated, and your `tmp` variable will turn into a dangling pointer. The `... retain] autorelease]` dance keeps the object around long enough to do the swap without having to worry about it deallocating before the end of the method (likely it will stick around until the top of the next run loop).